# Как реализовать добавление изображение между текстом в постах

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Делаю блог. Есть админка, посты можно как создавать так и редактировать.
Структура в панеле редактирования сейчас такая

- заголовок ( input[text] )
- Главное изображение ( input[file] )
- текст ( textarea )
- метки

Текст пишу в textarea и сохраняю в бд ( полный html ).

Как реализовать добавление изображений в текст типо так:

- текст
- изображение
- изображение
- текст

Изображения создаю и храню ссылку в бд.

Comment: На сколько мне известно, это не возможно.
Пиши в разных сообщениях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно очень по-всякому.
1) Подыскать готовое решение редактора. Может быть очень тяжелым и слишком накрученным. Но выбор тут велик
2) Заменить текстэриа блоком с атрибутом contenteditable. Там из коробки есть специальный метод полнофункционального редактирования контента (почитайте про `execCommand()`), он же, в свою очередь, включает в себя тип 'insertimage'. Можно добавлять в блок изображения по url-адресу. Примерно так:

```
<div id='editor' contentEditable />
```

```
document.execCommand('insertimage', false, 'http://site.com/anyimage.jpg')
```

Кстати, если вторым аргументом указывать true, то браузер должен будет предоставить специальную кнопку в contenteditable-блоке для интеграции изображений.
Этот метод нужно больше калибровать - кроме того, contentEditable-блоки надо защищать от атак (в блок по умолчанию, разумеется, можно вставить любой тег, хоть даже script)
3) Реализовать ваш редактор блочно: как статьи в вк. Скажем, есть textarea, а после него кнопка, которой можно добавитьь после него блок с изображением. Тут надо кодить больше всего, зато получится точно красивей (и безопасней)